Do I need to make all the class attributes private and define a public method for them in Python?
I really do not know which one is better when an attribute is used outside of class.
define it as a public attribute:
class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 0


test = Test()
test.a += 1
print(test.a)

define it private and make public methods to change or read it:
class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__a = 0

    def a(self) -> None:
        return self.__a

    def increase_a(self) -> None:
        self.__a += 1

test = Test()
test.increase_a()
print(test.a())


Do the first one. If you ever actually need to intervene you can migrate to properties without changing the API. And __dunder isn't "private", it's name mangled.

short answer: no!

The first one is "more Pythonic". So go with that one. If you do want to make it a "protected" attribute (protected from being changed to a dict for example) you can make it a property and use the property decorators on it to get and set it.

Is this what you're looking for? What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters? The top answer is pretty brief, but Aaron Hall's answer gives a lot more info.

No.
that is not the way the language is intended to be used.
If class Test has a documented attribute a, users of the class should know when and when not to change it.
If for some reason you need to guard access to a (either to constrain values or types, or when it can be changed, for example), you can make a property out of your attribute, and all code that uses Test can continue unchanged - but access to .a will from now on be guarded by code.
But unless you need it for an attribute, you should not do it, you are just writing useless boilerplate code.
class Test:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.a = "whatever"  # note that access from within methods can go through the unmodified ".a" name

     @property
     def a(self):  # getter code
         return self._a
     @a.setter
     def a(self, value):
         if not isinstance(a, str):   # for example
              raise TypeError(...)
         self._a = a

Just for enphasis: even using property descriptors as above, which allow the guarded access to go through the usual = operation, it is not needed.  Just add getters and setters if you have something to do in that code.
For increasing a you can write just instance.a += 1 - this code will call the getter, read the current value, add one (or, if the object retrieved on read supports in place add, call that method with 1), and call the setter to write the new value there. If you need the increase_a to be atomic because ou are writing multi-threaded code, then yes, you have to create the method and use a threading.Lock object to obtain the atomicity. (Again, your users will only know they have to call increase_a instead of doing a += 1 if you document it properly)
